# OpenERP on VPS, and redirection of Postgresql to Local Machine

Tags: postgresql, ssh, odoo, vps, pgadmin

Please, any help will be appreciated, i have an **OpenERP** installed with all its components (**Postgres**, **Web server**, **Server**) in a **VPS**..

And I would like to use this PostgreSQL from my local machine trough pgAdmin3. I am still not able to do so.

I read some answers about this issue, by modifing **Configuration Files in Postgresql** and some others telling me to use **SSH Tunilling trough Putty**, but when i go to connect trough PGADMIN3 **i can't have a successfuull connection**

So , Please if any one could Give me in details What i have to do, to make this happen successfully,

Comment: PLease i hope that someone Can Help ! ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ask yourself a bunch of questions.  The answer to this isn't really that simple which is why it hasn't been answered.  These involve risk management questions that happen when you set up your db for access across the internet.  You really want to start by reading the administration and authentication sections of the PostgreSQL docs.  You may want to do an SSH tunnel or just require SSL.

Personally I would configure PostgreSQL to require SSL if you are going to do that.   Set up an entry of type hostssl in the pg_hba.conf for the host that will be connecting to it.  Set up firewall rules to allow connections from that host.  Ideally set up a client cert but not quite sure how to make OpenERP use that.

Then configure OpenERP.  I don't know which version you are running but [these docs](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/01_getting_started.html#configuration-files-link) may get you started.